# RectTransforms spontaneously returning to old size

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a script that rotates some cubes around to mimic a slot machine. I updated the transforms size from 45 px per size to 40. The script is still behaving as if they were 45 by 45. I can't imagine why this is happening.

All transforms are 40 px in the inspector.
The transforms are moving by 45 pix as their speed. I don't know why.
I tried Space.Self, same thing.
The transforms even space themselves out to their old locations when the resetting function is called.

Any ideas?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Reel : MonoBehaviour
```

{

```
//This Variable Will Be Changed By The "Slots" Class To Control When The Reel Spins 
public bool spin;

//Speed That Reel Will Spin
float speed;

public int updates = 0;

// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    spin = false;
    speed = 0.2f;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (spin)
    {
        foreach (Transform image in transform)//This Targets All Children Objects Of The Main Parent Object fghjfgh smooth Time.smoothDeltaTime *
        {
            //Direction And Speed Of Movement
            image.transform.Translate(Vector2.right * speed, Space.World);

            //Once The Image Moves Below A Certain Point, Reset Its Position To The Top
            if (image.transform.position.x >= +3) { image.transform.position = new Vector2(image.transform.position.x -6, image.transform.position.y); }
        }
        updates = updates + 1;
    }
}

//Once The Reel Finishes Spinning The Images Will Be Placed In A Random Position
public void RandomPosition()
{
    List<int> parts = new List<int>();

    //Add All Of The Values For The Original Y Postions 
    parts.Add(2);
    parts.Add(1);
    parts.Add(0);
    parts.Add(-1);
    parts.Add(-2);
    parts.Add(-3);


    foreach (Transform image in transform)
    {
        int rand = Random.Range(0, parts.Count);

        //The "transform.parent.GetComponent<RectTransform>().transform.position.y" Allows It To Adjust To The Canvas Y Position)
        image.transform.position = new Vector2(parts[rand] + transform.parent.GetComponent<RectTransform>().transform.position.x, image.transform.position.y);

        parts.RemoveAt(rand);
    }
}
```

}

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Slots : MonoBehaviour
```

{

```
public Reel[] reel;
bool startSpin;


// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    startSpin = false;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (!startSpin)//Prevents Interference If The Reels Are Still Spinning
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.K))//The Input That Starts The Slot Machine
        {
            startSpin = true;
            StartCoroutine(Spinning());
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.H))//The Input That Starts The Slot Machine
        {
            reel[0].RandomPosition();
        }
    }
}

IEnumerator Spinning()
{
    foreach (Reel spinner in reel)
    {
        //Tells Each Reel To Start Spnning
        spinner.spin = true;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < reel.Length; i++)
    {
        //Allow The Reels To Spin For A Random Amout Of Time Then Stop Them
        //yield return new WaitForSeconds(Random.Range(1, 3));

        while (reel[0].updates != 100)
        {
            yield return null;
        }
        reel[0].spin = false;
        reel[0].updates = 0;

    }

    //Allows The Machine To Be Started Again
    startSpin = false;
}
```

}

Comment: Can you provide some screenshots?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/o5d9v6
http://prntscr.com/o5da0r
http://prntscr.com/o5da3t

before, after rotation and after reset

Comment: Are you using a horizontal layout group?

Comment: Nope, no layout group. This is the container: http://prntscr.com/o5dgp9

Comment: Transforms don't have sizes, RectTransforms do, I am not sure if this is the root of your problem but it could lead somewhere. also your script doesn't seem to affect the size at all

Comment: I had a play around and transforms dont seem to influence things. What did influence the gap was the size of the canvas x axis. I am very confused as to why this wshould, because I can remove references to world space and still get the same issue.

Comment: I also moved the entire prefab to a new project and had the same issue. I also remade the entire thing using the same script and same issue.

Comment: I have included the entire code for both scripts to help find the issue.